# Android facebook sdk install and sharing

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to android development and I am trying to make a simple app that integrates with facebook.

so, I red some articles and tuts about it and I can't figure out some things:
in order to install facebook sdk, I saw that I need to register a new android app on facebook, and give them the package address and main activity address on the google play. but, my app is on my computer and I didnt publish it so how can I give them my package name?

second, generating key hashes, also my app is on my computer and I didnt publish it so how can I generate a hash key without key store?

thank you for your help

Comment: Refer here for complete detail:http://coderzpassion.com/android-using-facebook-login-application-using-latest-facebook-sdk/

Comment: Read carefully the Getting Started guide in Facebook Developer site

Comment: Raprot - I have red it all step by step but for some reason I guess I am missing somethig because it doesn't work. @JagjitSingh I red what you gave me, but I am facing trouble making the hash key - I got a hash key with the alias that facebook wants (androiddebuger) but when I enter the hashkey in facebook site, it doesn't verify it.

Comment: @dani jinji U building with Command or Function? try changing the method with which u are building and then retry